# Accordion + Appended Content Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, accordion

So I have an accordion menu that I created with Jquery:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/*Accordian Script for the Request New Appraisal Panel*/
$('.accordian_item').hide();
$('.accordian_item').first().slideDown();

$('.accordian_trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.accordian_item').slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Now, I want to be able to dynamically append extra accordion items to the accordion box, which I have done like this:

```
<script>

$('#add_contact_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var large = '<div class="accordian_container"><a href="#" class="accordian_trigger"><h4>Co-Borrower Information</h4></a><hr/><div class="accordian_item"><label> First Name</label><br/><input type="text"/><br/><label>Middle Name</label><br/><input type="text"/><br/><label>Last Name</label><br/><input type="text" /><br/><label>Home Number</label><br/><input type="text"/><br><label>Work Number</label><br/><input type="text"/><br><label>Cell Number</label><br/><input type="text"/><br></div></div>';

    $('#accordion_container_box').append(large);


});
</script>
```

This works perfect, except the dynamically generated items don't collaps when you click on the collapse button. The existing accordion items still work.  For some reason it seems like Jquery wont trigger for dynamically created links. Any ideas how I can correct this?

BTW, here is the basic HTML structure:

```
<div id="accordion_container_box">

            <div class="accordian_container">
                <a href="#" class="accordian_trigger"><h4>Borrower's Information</h4></a>
                <hr/>
                <div class="accordian_item">
                <label> First Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br/>
                <label>Middle Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br/>
                <label>Last Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Home Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                <label>Work Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                <label>Cell Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="accordian_container">       
                <a href="#" class="accordian_trigger"><h4>Co-Borrower's Information</h4></a>
                <hr/>
                <div class="accordian_item">
                <label> First Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br/>
                <label>Middle Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br/>
                <label>Last Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" /><br/>
                <label>Home Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                <label>Work Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                <label>Cell Number</label><br/>
                <input type="text"/><br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

            <a href="#" id="add_contact_btn">+ Additional Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use .live('click'... on dynamically created content.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 1):

By default binding events to elements will only affect nodes that exist at the time that the bind runs.  By using event delegation you can make use of the built in way that events bubble.  jQuery < 1.7 did this with the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) methods, jQuery 1.7 added the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to consolidate all the event handlers in a single API.

For example you could use the following to handle all clicks on nodes with a class of `accordian_trigger` regardless of when they were created.

```
​$(document).on('click', '.accordian_trigger', function() {
    //whatever you need to do
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

What this will do is attach an `onclick` event handler to the `document` itself.  When any click occurs in the DOM it will bubble up from the node that the event occurred on to its parent and its parent until it reaches the `document`.  jQuery will then check whether the event occurred on a node that matches the selector passed in as the second parameter of `on`, in this case it will check whether the node has a class of `accordian_trigger`.  If it does it will run the `function` passed in as the third parameter.

For efficiency's sake you'll likely want to replace `document` with a parent node that you know will contain all `accordian_trigger` nodes.  Otherwise **all** clicks bubble all the way up to the `document` and check whether the node that was clicked on has the `accordian_trigger` class, which is potentially expensive, especially if you have a large DOM.